# View current version of email in a live triggered send

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, email

Where can I go see the current version of the email that is in a live trigger email send.

I know that you can make changes in content builder but that doesn't publish changes to the live trigger without you going in and telling it to.  So the question is, where can I go if I want to see what the current trigger send email looks like?

Comment: The only way I reckon you can see this is in the TRACKING > SENDS within email studio .  There's a preview window, albeit a small window.

Answer (score 1):

As per the triggered send setup the email changes do not reflect on the live emails unless triggered send definition is stopped, published and restarted.

However, if this is the case where you'd like to see the current version of email used in triggered send definition, then you could use get **[Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps)** which can perform various types of API requests and use your email address to create a API request payload.

This way you will be able to see the version of the email that triggered send definition is running with.

For this purpose:

- The right client ID and secret key as well as triggered send external key needs to be setup in Postman request. You can also use the API username and Password for this purpose.
- The REST or SOAP header and body will need to be setup accordingly in Postman.
- The API payload format has to match with the Triggered Send Data Extension to which the email is linked.

References:

[- Create Triggered Send Definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_triggered_send_definition.htm)

[- REST API Message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_triggered_send_definition.htm)

[- SOAP API Message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/send_triggeredsend_email.htm)